# Conditional maping in mapstruct

Tags: jackson, mapstruct

i have dto from jackson and its update database with orm hibernate :

```
class dto {

string f1;
bool isModifiedF1;

string f2;
bool isModifiedF2;

setF1(str s) {
this.isModifiedF1 = true;
this.f1 = s;
}

setF2(str s) {
this.isModifiedF2 = true;
this.f2 = s;
}

//othre setter like that
}
```

i like to hava thigs like this :

```
classMpperImpl {

modify(dto , entity) {

if(dto.isModifedF1){
entity.setF1(dto.getF1);
}

if(dto.isModifedF2){
entity.setF1(dto.getF2);
}

//and other method

}


}
```

how to do that ?
i locking soulotion to work with all field and for now i just ignore that important field i need and set it manally with @AfterMapping
i need to avoid any not chaged field in hibernate like casade create field ...

thank you

Comment: I know have spi , i dont know how to implementation it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapStruct has the notion of presence checking. More info in the [Source presence checking](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#source-presence-check) section of the reference documentation.

What you actually need to to is to use something like `hasF1` and MapStruct will invoke that method. For your particular example this will look like:

```
class Dto {

    private string f1;
    private boolean isModifiedF1;

    private string f2;
    private boolean isModifiedF2;

    public boolean hasF1() {
        return isModifiedF1;
    }

    public void setF1(str s) {
        this.isModifiedF1 = true;
        this.f1 = s;
    }

    public boolean hasF2() {
        return isModifiedF2;
    }

    public void setF2(str s) {
        this.isModifiedF2 = true;
        this.f2 = s;
    } 

    // Others
}
```

And then in the generated code MapStruct will do something like

```
class DtoMapperImpl {

    public void modify(Dto dto, Entity entity) {

    if(dto.hasF1()){
        entity.setF1(dto.getF1());
    }

    if(dto.hasF2()){
        entity.setF2(dto.getF2());
    }

    //and other method

}
```